# Creating a sorted list of unique numbers from a DataFrame

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I am writing keywords and their corresponding page numbers via LaTeX into textfiles which i then process with Python. How can I create a sorted list of page numbers with their corresponding keyword?

The following code gives me the unique list however it is not sorted.

```
import pandas as pd

def unique(liste):
    a = liste.split(',')
    a = [int(numeric_string) for numeric_string in a]
    a = sorted(a)
    a = map(str,a)
    b = set(a)
    return ','.join(b)

df = pd.DataFrame({'keyword': ["foo","foo","foo","foo","foo","foo","foo","foo","bar","bar","bar"], "page": [1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,9,10]})
df['page'] = df['page'].astype(str)
print(df)

grouped = df.groupby('keyword',as_index=False).agg(lambda col: ','.join(col))
grouped = pd.DataFrame(grouped)
grouped['unique'] = grouped['page'].apply(unique)
print(grouped)
```

produces

```
   keyword page
0      foo    1
1      foo    2
2      foo    3
3      foo    3
4      foo    4
5      foo    5
6      foo    6
7      foo    7
8      bar    7
9      bar    9
10     bar   10
  keyword             page         unique
0     bar           7,9,10         9,7,10
1     foo  1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7  3,7,6,4,5,2,1
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'keyword': ["foo","foo","foo","foo","foo","foo","foo","foo","bar","bar","bar"], 
     "page": [1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,9,10]})

# df['page'] = df['page'].astype(int)
result = df.groupby(['keyword'])['page'].agg(lambda x: ','.join(np.unique(x).astype(str)))

print(result)
```

yields

```
keyword
bar           7,9,10
foo    1,2,3,4,5,6,7
Name: page, dtype: object
```

---

- `np.unique` returns a unique *sorted* array of values. We want the page values to be sorted as ints (not as strings) so keep `page` values as ints. After calling `np.unique` you can use `astype(str)` to convert to strings and then join them with `','.join`.